# Real Time Compositor Viewport Preview Glare not exactly the same as Final Render

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I am using real-time compositing but the final render is not showing like viewport.

This is the final render:

[image]

This is the viewport render:

[image]

Compositor setup:

[image]

Render Pass: Combined

Compositor enabled in post-processing and set to Always and Camera in Options.

I am rendering in cycles using GPU compute.

Comment: Please do not rely on external sources, you can edit pictures directly into your question. And please make the screenshot of the nodetree large enough so that the nodes are legible. It would also be interesting if you are rendering in _Eevee_ or _Cycles_.

Comment: Hey Gordon , I tried dropping the render and the screenshot directly but it says the size is too big . I will update the node-tree shot as well , thank you

Comment: To see the different outcome it is not necessary to have a full resolution PNG, a JPG would have a smaller size and maybe you could even make the image itself smaller. You could enable _Backdrop_ in the _Compositor_ and use a _Viewer_ node, usually this should show what the outcome will look like - as far as I know the viewport compositing is still in the works and not everything and every node works exactly like in post compositing.

Comment: I thought some details will be lost during converting , but i m uploading another format for simplicity , btw i am rendering in cycles using gpu compute

Comment: Some details maybe, but at first glance I would say the glare effect is massivley different, so no need to worry about details... stupid question: "set to Always and Camera in Options" - I can only choose one, not both at the same time. Which one is it?

Comment: Yes i use the viewer-node for testing different nodes behaviour in the tree , thats what i thought also about the instability of some nodes in the compositor in real-time , is real-time compositing still in the testing stage regarding development ?

No thats a good question , i meant wether i am choosing Camera or Always , it doesnt change the final render ( not using both of them at the same time )

Comment: Not really testing stage, but still not fully functional and a work in progress as far as I know. But we are only users here, no developers or in any way affiliated with Blender, so I can only guess.

Comment: I see , it's definitely a great upgrade for the real-time , and btw the render changes everytime i re-visit the project , so as you said it's still work in progress ! I ll keep that in mind , Thank you Gordon , appreciate

Answer (score 2):

Glare node in Fog Glow mode has size property that controls the glare size in pixels. It looks stronger when the resolution of the image is smaller, because  there are reletively more pixels affected by it than when the resolution is higher. Increase the glare size according to the full resolution image.

Comment: If I see it correctly in that small nodetree image, there is also a _Lens Distortion_ node before the _Glare_ node. The effect varies with image pixels, too.

Comment: Hey Martynas , sorry for the small node tree image .Thank you for your response . I just noticed that the size is in pixels ,
 but the maximum size in the node is 9 , how can i match 9 px of  the node to the 1920 by 1080 px of the image ? 
and yes it's a lense distortion node in there

Comment: @Tune Oh, since a new question is directed to this older question I forgot to say back then: there is a slight misunderstanding, the _Size_ property does not control the glare size in pixels. It controls the **scale** of the glare **relative** to the size of the bright pixels. So it is depending on the pixel size of the emissive elements, but it is not setting the size of the glare in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation , the glare node has this comment :

Viewport compositing results will vary from CPU compositing due to different algorithms.

So i think it's the reason

Comment: Correct, this is documented. Both compositor backends don't produce exactly the same result. That should be consolidated in next Blender versions.